# Migrating to FCM and Android O - Is launching an IntentService still valid?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, intentservice, android-workmanager

I'm currently updating my project to targetSdkVersion 26 (Android O) and also migrating from GCM to FCM.

Currently I have:

- A `RegistrationIntentService` that fetches the GCM token and posts this token to a server.
- `MainActivity` that checks for `GooglePlayServices` and then starts the `RegistrationIntentService`.
- A `MyInstanceIDListenerService` which has the `onTokenRefresh` method that just starts the `RegistrationIntentService`.

This was based on a Google [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java).

To migrate to FCM I just had to change `MyInstanceIDListenerService` to inherit from `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and `RegistrationIntentService` now uses `FirebaseInstanceId` to get the token.

Everything seems to work ok, I tested it in an Android O emulator.

However, I know that Android O is limiting background services. So, I was wondering if it's still ok in an app that targets Android O to start the `RegistrationIntentService` from the `MainActivity` and `MyInstanceIDListenerService`.

Or should I move the `RegistrationIntentService` code to a task to be executed by the `WorkManager`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight answer to your question, because it is depending on your use-case, especially on how much processing you need to complete when the `RegistrationIntentService` is called.
You can still use `IntentService` on Oreo while your app is in the foreground or when it receives certain events, like a data push.

However, you can simply launch your `IntentService` in the background using [`JobIntentService.enqueueWork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html#enqueueWork(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) directly from your `onHandleIntent()` method, which means it will be executed when the OS is willing to sacrifice the resources for you.
Depending on the amount of work you might still need to create a foreground service, because your app will be white-listed for a while, but not for an extended period.

I am still trying to find any reference about how much time any background task might spend, though. So far I was relying on experiments, but this is not a reliable way of implementing any critical service, obviously.

Comment: Thanks. The background work is getting the FCM token using FirebaseInstanceId and then calling my own API service to register the FCM device token. So it should be completed usually in a couple of seconds or less.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that few seconds, it can take much more time, for example when it times out. I would suggest to launch your own `IntentService` using `JobIntentService.enqueueWork()`.

Comment: Thanks, I end up extending `JobIntentService` and launching it using `JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, RegistrationIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent)`. Also added `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` in manifest.